# UIScrollView with dynamic content

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm trying to implement a `UIScrollView`, but every tutorial out there deals with a preset number of items.

What I have are multiple `UITextField`'s, but the number of textfields vary. Basically, as soon as one  `textField` contains text, another empty one appears below it, allowing the user to fill in an unlimited number of textfields.

My code creates a new textfield as soon as the user types something into a previous one. The `x-coordinates`of this is the same as the previous one, but the `y-coordinates`to the new one equals the height of the previous + 5px.

I'm using storyboards, and I have placed my original `textField` within a `UIScrollView`. I have connected this `scrollView` to my code, and I add a new textfield this way: `[self.scrollView addSubview:newTextField];`

However, when the amount of `textFields` exceeds the `scrollView`, I cannot scroll to reveal the new one that's been added.

How would I go about doing this? I don't think I completely get the `setContentSize` thing, so it might have something to do with that. Here are some pictures and code to explain my problem:

**Code to add new textfield:**

```
UITextField *newTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(textField.frame.origin.x, textField.frame.origin.y + textField.frame.size.height+5, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height)];
newTextField.placeholder = @"Add more text";
newTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
newTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
newTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
newTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
newTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
newTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
[newTextField setTag:textFieldTag];
newTextField.delegate = self;
[self.scrollView addSubview:newTextField];
```

**Storyboard:**

[image: Here you can see how I have placed the original textfield within my scrollview]

Here you can see how I have placed the original textfield within my scrollview

**How it looks in the simulator:**

[image: When you enter text in the textfield, this happens:]

**When you enter text in the textfield, this happens:**

[image: An empty textfield appears below the previous one]

An empty textfield appears below the previous one.

**However, when you exceed the ScrollView, this happens**

[image: You can no longer see the new textfield, because it is below the scrollView]

You can no longer see the new textField because it is below the scrollView's boundaries. You can not scroll to reveal it either.

---

Does anyone know how to solve this? And if you have time, how would you make it so the scrollview automatically scrolls down to reveal the new textfield that's been added?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why did you decide against a table view? It seems to be a much better fit for this problem.

Comment: I considered a tableview, but ultimately decided against it because I will have more information on the screen than what you can see from the images (among others an image to the right and so on). However, a tableview is my backup solution if this is impossible.

Comment: Post the code for how you update `contentSize`.

Comment: NOTE: it should look something like `self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectMaxX(newTextField.frame), CGRectMaxY(newTextField.frame))`

Comment: As I said, I didn't quite get the `contentSize` thing. Is it supposed to be the size of the content? Does the size of the actual `UIScrollView` matter? Where should I set it? As for now I have set it in the `ViewDidLoad` function at a random (small) number to see if it will scroll, but it wouldn't. What should be my initial `contentSize`? Should I update it as I add new text fields?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `contentSize` needs to be the size of content contained within the scroll view.

If the `contentSize` is wider than the `bounds.size`, then you can scroll left and right. If the `contentSize` is taller than the `bounds.size`, then you can scroll up and down.

You need to set the `contentSize` to be the entire area you wish to contain within your scroll view.

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(textField.frame.origin.x, textField.frame.origin.y + textField.frame.size.height+5, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height)];
textField.placeholder = @"Add more text";
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.tag = textFieldTag;
textField.delegate = self;

[self.scrollView addSubview:textField];

// Update the contentSize to include the new text field.
CGFloat width = self.scrollView.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat height = CGRectGetMaxY(textField.frame);
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

NOTES:

- Don't start variables or methods with `new`. It has special meaning and you will confuse other Objective-C developers and/or the compiler.
- `textField.tag = …` is the same as `[textfield setTag:…];` You seem to like the dot syntax in other places, so I switched to that.
- I'm assuming you don't want the scroll view to pan left and right, so I pinned the content width to the scroll view's width.

Comment: What is `CGRectMaxY`? The compiler doesn't seem to like it, and I can't find anything about it online. It says **Implicit declaration of function 'CGRectMaxY' is invalid in C99**

Comment: And what should I initialize the contentSize as? I start out with a textfield `self.textField2`, so what should I add in the `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @Alekplay should have been [CGRectGetMaxY](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectGetMaxY).

Comment: The `contentSize` is the area of the context. You just need a Rect which completely encloses your content. If your content is only 1 text field, then you can set it to be the size of that text field.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will try it as soon as I get back to my computer! I'll let you know if it works or not! :)

Comment: Thank you so much @JefferyThomas! That works!

But I have another question! In my `textFieldDidEndEditing` I check if any of the textfields are empty, and if one is, I remove the last one and push all the text up. That way there is always one, and only one, empty textfield at the end.

How would I implement something in that method that **decreases** the contentSize by one textField?

Also, how would I implement something in such a way that the physical size of the `scrollview` is from the start to the bottom of the screen, OR the top of the keyboard if it is present?

Comment: I managed to solve the **decrease contentsize** problem, but my second question still stands. How would I make the physical size of the **scrollview** depend on whether I have the keyboard up or not? And another thing, how do I make the scrollview scroll down to reveal the new textfield that's been added?

Comment: These are separate questions. You should either search stack overflow for the answer or post them as a new question.