# UIScrollview with Button and Text Fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am attempting to generate text fields, and buttons inside of a `UIScrollview`. I am attempting every time I hit the button to generate another text field, and button under it on the scroll view which would create a never ending cycle. I am creating a simple story telling app. Using a `UIScrollview` allows the user to be able to scroll all the way at the beginning to see all of his choices. Not sure how to start this.

Comment: It is better to user UITableView instead of UIscrollview, it is easily managable i think....!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField  alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(textField.frame.origin.x, textField.frame.origin.y + textField.frame.size.height+5, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height)]; 
textField.placeholder = @"Add more text";
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];     
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes; 
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; 
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences; 
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.tag = textFieldTag; 
textField.delegate = self;

[self.scrollView addSubview:textField];

// Update the contentSize to include the new text field. 
CGFloat width = self.scrollView.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat height = CGRectGetMaxY(textField.frame);  
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

Create dynamic buttons and textfields as above.

You can refer following links;

1) [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888508/uiscrollview-with-dynamic-content)

2) [Link2](http://nscookbook.com/2015/06/ios-programming-recipe-36-a-fixed-width-dynamic-height-scrollview-in-autolayout/)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tableview with adding a new row on each button tap might be much more straight forward. But you will have to maintain the states of the textfields etc and populate them on each reload.