# How to dynamically size UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm adding content to the UIScrollView dynamically. The content size of the scroll view is increasing. How can I change the content size to fit the dynamically added content? See the code I'm using that is not working

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func updateContentView() {
        contentSize.height = subviews.sorted(by: { $0.frame.maxY < $1.frame.maxY }).last?.frame.maxY ?? contentSize.height
        contentSize.height += 300
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> [refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22889576/10175156)

I hope the above solves your problem but I'd prefer using a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView` in place of this because everything is handled so smoothly in them. You just have to give the number of rows(return a variable which changes dynamically). That's it, your `contentSize` is adjusted internally.

But again if you have a different requirement please go with the reference link!